# How do I correctly write this comparator for Collections.sort(arrayList, comparator)?

Tags: java, comparable

I have written a comparator to compare 2 objects.

The methods for each object should, hopefully, be self explanatory.  When I place my `ArrayList` into `Collections.sort(arrayList, comparator)`, it does not sort at all.

```
public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
final int followersComparison = Integer.compare(o2.getWhoThisUserIsBeingFollowedBy().size(), o1.getWhoThisUserIsBeingFollowedBy().size());

if (followersComparison != 0) {
  return followersComparison;
}

final int followingComparison = Integer.compare(o2.getWhoThisUserIsFollowing().size(), o1.getWhoThisUserIsFollowing().size());

if (followingComparison != 0) {
  return followingComparison;
}

// Note here o1 and o2 is in opposite order than above
return  Integer.compare(o1.getUserId(), o2.getUserId());
```

}

I am expecting `Collections.sort` to sort my `ArrayList` according to this comparator, but it doesn't.

Comment: you can debug it through in line by line, to check what's wrong.

Comment: I did debug it and it hits the first if statement and then returns out of it.

Comment: For starters, you're failing to return early; there's no use in having your `x` as a variable. That said, `Comparator.comparingInt(user -> user.getFollowers().size()).thenComparingInt(User::getUserId)`. And wouldn't it make more sense to compare by the number of follows *before* the user ID?

Answer (score 1):

Hows this:

```
public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
    final int followersComparison = Integer.compare(o2.getWhoThisUserIsBeingFollowedBy().size(), o1.getWhoThisUserIsBeingFollowedBy().size());

    if (followersComparison != 0) {
      return followersComparison;
    }

    final int followingComparison = Integer.compare(o2.getWhoThisUserIsFollowing().size(), o1.getWhoThisUserIsFollowing().size());

    if (followingComparison != 0) {
      return followingComparison;
    }

    // Note here o1 and o2 is in opposite order than above
    return  Integer.compare(o1.getUserId(), o2.getUserId());

  }
```

It seems that you might have missed some else parts when comparing numbers (e.g. you only return 1 if `o1.getwhoThisUserIsBeingFollowedBy().size() > 02.getwhoThisUserIsBeingFollowedBy().size()` but what if it is the other way around). I tend to do the same mistake, that's why I prefer to use Integer.compare

Comment: Thanks Pavel!  I am still learning and sometimes when I am working to debug I end up with blinders on.  I'll test it and let you know.